# Hyperplane vs Projective Lines

Tags: geometry, curves, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, projective-space

My definition for hyperplanes in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is the locus of pts. $[x_0, \ldots, x_n]$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$ satisfying a linear equation $\sum a_i x_i = 0$ where $(a_0, \ldots, a_n) \neq 0$. So my question is: Aren't hyperplane just equivalent to projective lines? If so why are there two definition for it?

Comment: They are equivalent for $n=2$ only.

Comment: And why not for $n=3$ are bigger?

Comment: $\{ [x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3] | \sum a_i x_i =  0 \}$ is a general hyperplane and this a line!

Comment: In the 3d space, hyperplanes are 2d planes, in $n$d space, they are $(n-1)$ dimensional.

Comment: How can they be $2d$ plane? The poly defining it has degree 1

Comment: Yes, one linear equation can decrease the dimension at most by one.

Comment: Think about the same in real 3d space: the vectors satisfying a linear equation (say, $z=0$ for simplest example) lie on a 2d plane ($x,y$ can be arbitrary in the given example).

Comment: But in the $3d$ we have 4 coordinates

Comment: Projective 3d space arises from Euclidean 4d space, yes. One linear equation there defines a 3d hyperplane, which is mapped to a 2d hyperplane in the projective 3d space. I meant the Euclidean 3d case above.

Comment: Thanks for your time but I am still confused. So consider $\mathbb{P}^3$. Let $P(x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_0$. Then this polynomial defines a line as it degree $1$. But this is also the hyperplane given by $x_0 = 0$

Comment: I have been doing further reading and I was confused about the definition of a projective! I thought that a projective line was defined by the zeros of a poly of this degree $1$. I see that this is only the case for $n=2$.

Comment: That's exactly how I started :)

Answer (score 1):

If you forget the projective part, you get all the vectors that are *orthogonal* to a given nonzero vector $(a_0,\dots, a_n)$. 
That is a linear hyperplane ($n$ dimensional subspace) of the $n+1$ dimensional vector space.

Then taking homogeneous coordinates decreases the dimensions by $1$.